# Why does my loop in the timer control stops suddenly VB.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

Now when I have my code in my one project where this is the ONLY code (note, I got a listbox that is full of items around 29 items!), the function works properly and it loops through every single item and gives it out as a messagebox.

When I enter this code into my bigger project where I meticulously copy pasted the code, the loop in the timer stops after 3 times EVERY TIME. Even when I enter in the timer1.

```
If Count < "29" Then
```

Still it stops after three times EVERY TIME. What am I doing wrong, the sources are pretty much the same?!

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim NumberOfItems As Integer
    Dim Count As String

     Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
       If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            Button2.Text = "Stop Timer"
            NumberOfItems = ListBox1.Items.Count
            Count = "0"
        Else
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Text = "Start Timer"
        End If
End Sub

 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If Count < NumberOfItems Then
            Dim CurrentIt3m As String = ListBox1.Items(Count)
            MsgBox(CurrentIt3m)
            Count = Count + 1
        Else
            Button2.Text = "Start Timer"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` right away. Not a moment to lose.  `If Count < "29" Then` is comparing a numeric to a string. `"29"` is not the same as `29`.  The ***number*** `3` will test higher than `"29"`  because 3 > 2.  See [Data Types in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)  the quote is not an all purpose variable marker - it designates text/string type

Comment: Case study for the evil **Option Strict Off** Unbelievable that such wrongdoing is still the default for VB.NET

Comment: Where do I turn on option Strict?
Also: THANKS plutonix, I stupidly made the mistake of defining it as an string, whereas I declared the same variable in the working version as integer!!! That was the mistake!

Comment: Right click on your project properties, select Compile page, look in the Compile Options groupbox

Comment: Even better is to go to **Tools** menu, select **Options**, then the **Projects and Solutions Tab**, turn it on for **VB Defaults** so it will be the default setting for all new projects as it should be

Comment: You said "the loop in the timer stops after 3 times EVERY TIME" There is no loop in your code.